# Which loop do I use to ask if a user wants to continue the program in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I made a program that asks for input and returns a value. After, I want to ask if the user wants to continue. But I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `do..while` loop:

```
bool shouldContinue;
do {
    // get input
    // do operation
    // ask user to continue
    if ( Console.ReadLine() == "y" ) {
        shouldContinue = true;
    }
} while (shouldContinue);
```

Comment: This one was the easiest to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `do` / `while` loop, or an infinite `while` loop with a conditional `break`.

Answer (score 2):

A do-while loop is often used:

```
bool @continue = false;
do
{
    //get value
    @continue = //ask user if they want to continue
}while(@continue);
```

The loop will be executed once before the loop condition is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

This only allows 2 keys (Y and N):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
do {
    // do you work here
    Console.WriteLine("Press Y to continue, N to abort");

    do {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
    } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.N || keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Y);
} while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.N);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Do While` Loop. something similar will work

```
int input=0;
do
{  
  System.Console.WriteLine(Calculate(input)); 
  input =  GetUserInput();
} while (input != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a while loop here, something like:

```
bool doMore= true;

while(doMore) {
  //Do work
  //Prompt user, if they refuse, doMore=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, any loop will do it, a `for` loop for example (which is another way to write a `while(true){;}` )

```
    for (; true; )
    {
        //Do stuff
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "quit")
            {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("I am doing stuff");
    }
```